# Unions of polygons (Postgis ST_UNION for Geography type)

Tags: postgis, geometry

I am looking for a function that will return the intersection of 2 or more polygons (geography type).

I am aware of ST_UNION, ST_COLLECT but it works only for geometry type.

Answer (score 6):

You can cast to geometry and do the calculation. If your data goes over the poles or date-line that could be problematic. Also if you have long edges, in which the great-circle interpolation line differs from a simple cartesian interpolation. In those cases you might have to create your own aggregate function that re-projects to something reasonable before running the operation.

```
SELECT ST_Transform(
  ST_Union(ST_Transform(geog::geometry, 26910)),
  4326)::geography 
FROM the_table
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [bostongis](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sqlserver2008r2_oracle11gr2_postgis15_compare), there is no UNION that works on geography type. So you have to first cast geography to geometry:

```
geometry(geography(your_table.the_geom))
```

Then apply ST_UNION and cast back.

Comment: Shouldn't data be projected first? Does other functions, like ST_Intersection, ST_Diffrence return correct results if data is _geometry_ with srid WGS84. Perhaps it's good idea for separate question...

Comment: Well, it depends on the extends of your data. As Paul already mentioned, problems at the poles and date-line occur if you don't use an appropriate CRS.